# How can I build a React app and take the URL to the backend from a file outside the build?

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-build

I have a React app where I use a variable for setting the URL of the backend.

When I build it, the URL goes in the static files of the build.

I need to build a React app where I can change URL of the backend, taking it from an external file (external to the build).

Is it possible to do? If so, how?

Comment: This is not easy to guess, what you want. At least give the problem description and example if possible.

Comment: Maybe store them in a json file in public directory and request that file using axios ? Usually we use `env` files for different environment like, `dev`, `staging` and `production` etc. So when building the project, we give instructions to look in a given `env` file to get the url.

Answer (score 2):

You can create different environment files likes **.env.dev** or **.env.prod**. In these files, every variable must be prepended with `REACT_APP_` in order to work. So for example: `REACT_APP_API_URL = "https://api.com/"`

Then you would have to update your **package.json** file with new *start* commands:

```
"start:development": "env-cmd -f .env.dev npm-run-all"
"start:production": "env-cmd -f .env.prod npm-run-all"
```

Read more about it [here](https://www.opcito.com/blogs/managing-multiple-environment-configurations-in-react-app/).